Exporting Alembic Hair to Unreal always comes out with wrong transforms
Every time I try to export the hair I made with the new Geometry Nodes hair tools in Blender to UE5 as an Alembic file it comes out sideways. I've tried resetting the transforms and setting the origin to center but nothing works.
How to fix this?



